# Can't access my computer with its public ip

Tags: macos, networking, ipv6

I installed [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info) on my Macbook Pro. It opens on 'localhost:8888'. I went to http://www.whatismyip.com/ and it gave me my ipv4 address. I copied my ip and put it on my browser like this: `myip:8888` and hit enter, but nothing opens.

Then I went to OS X's firewall and saw that it was off. So what's wrong?

I need to point out two things however:

1- When I go to Google and type: `what is my ip`, I get another address like this: `2a02:4061:8380:1000:f025:463f:1412:ea39`

2- When I enter `[2a02:4061:8380:1000:f025:463f:1412:ea39]:8888` into any browser, it fails immediately as if the browser doesn't recognize this kind of address. I think it's IPv6 but it can't recognize that it's even an address.

Edit: I'm connected to the internet through wifi, from my router: [My router has only IPv6 and I need to host websites](https://superuser.com/questions/781341/my-router-has-only-ipv6-and-i-need-to-host-websites)

Edit: `Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to [2a02:4061:8380:1000:f025:463f:1412:ea39]`

[image]

Comment: Please include your browser’s actual exact error message in your question.

Comment: Its actually normal for you to be unable to navigate to your localhost using your public address within a NAT configuration.  The question I have can another device connect to that address.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you connect to the internet to some sort of Router/Gateway, the public IP you get points to this device and not to your computer. Most Routers provide settings to forward ports to an IP address within the internal network. So if your Mac has the IP 192.168.1.2, you have to configure the portforwarding to forward port 8888 to that IP.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem here's what worked for me:

1. Go to your Modem's url (usually it's 192.168.2.1)
2. Go to advanced Firewall Settings
3. Create a new custom rule
4. Choose the port you want (for basic HTTP traffic it's 80)
5. Enable all traffic for that port

Basically, your modem / firewall will block all incoming web traffic, naturally. You must specifically allow for this kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

I guess your computer is not connected directly to the internet. You probably have a router inbetween. This router handles the local network (LAN) and the connection to the outside world (WAN). The public IP address you see is from the router. To send outside traffic via the router to your machine, you need to use Port Forwarding, and then allow port 80 (or 8888) to the IP of your machine.

Answer (score -1):

As the other dudes says, the ip that whatsmyip shows is from your router/modem and to you can access your pc from internet you you need to configure the router following the steeps bellow.

**1º Fix the IP address of your macbook.** 
It's needed to assure that your router/modem don't change your macbook ip address
You can do it in you macbook (configuring manually the ip address) or reservating one in you Router/modem, to do it you will need to know the networks interface's mac address of your Macbook .

**2º Configure one NAT rule on your Router/Modem.**
It's needed to grant acces from the internet to your local network (192.168.1.x).
*some router (cheaper ones) dont heave this function*. Basically the NAT rule use these parameters "External IP Address":"External acess port" (redirecting to) "Internal IP Address":"Internal Access Port".
Eg.Source = [2a02:4061:8380:1000:f025:463f:1412:ea39]:8888 Destination = 192.168.1.2:8888 Protocol = TCP or UDP

> *Remember that after do it ANY ONE from internet will be able to access
>   your personal computer / home network (of course, only the protocol,
>   address and port that you config) but some bad mans can explore
>   vulnerabilities and if them have success access your personal data.
>   Think about it.*